# Access Modifier in Ruby

Tags: ruby, private-methods

I can't understand this behavior. Please point me to a detailed answer. I created an object of class `Parent`:

```
class Parent
  private
  def name
    'Mommy'
  end
end
p = Parent.new
```

This raises an error:

```
p.name
# => NoMethodError: private method `name' called for #<Parent:0x0000000182a360>
```

but, the following gives the value.

```
p.send(:name)
# => "Mommy"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the wonderful insights.  Can anyone share a link with detailed info.

Comment: While digging deeper, i found that setter method can be called with explicit receiver for private methods. Please check this link for the example. https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/157911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, *private* methods can't be invoked with an *explicit* receiver. -- This is a *rule* hard-coded. If you try, MRI will object/complain as what you got.

But using `#send`, you are not breaking the rule, thus no objections.

`p.send(:name)`, you are calling method `#send` on `p`, and at the same time passing the method name(`:name`) as a symbol, to call the method. This is indeed a indirect approach. But in `p.name`, it is a direct method call of the method `#name` on `p`. That's all the differences about the 2 approaches.

No where it is written, you can't call *private* methods, but *it is written, not with explicit receiver, you can call it*.

Answer (score 2):

That is the whole point of `private` methods. In the first form, you have an explicit receiver. In the second form, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

The `send` method can access any method, whether it's public, private, or protected.  If you want a method that respects methods' privacy, try [`public_send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send).